# Hive Query to select lines that meet multiple criteria

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table that looks something like this (Column 1 is a URL, column 2 is an action ID, and column 3 is a user ID):

```
1    2    3   
=========== 
d    x    a   
d    q    a 
e    y    a
f    z    a
f    z    b
d    i    b
e    x    b
d    i    c
g    q    c
o    q    c
f    q    c
```

I'm trying to check and see if there are any rows where col1 = 'f'.

If col1 = 'f', I need to get the userID from col3 then check all rows where col3 = userID to see if there are any rows where col2 = 'x'.

If there are any userIDs that have a row where col1 = 'f' and a row where col2 = 'x', return all rows that have userID in col3

I'm a hive/sql noob, but here is some python code that i think would accomplish what I'm trying to do...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df2 = df[df['1'].str.contains('f')]
df2['check'] = df2['2'].str.contains('x')
ids = df2[df2['check']]
df = df[df['3'].isin(ids)]
```

The result of my desired query would return

```
1    2    3   
=========== 
d    x    a   
d    q    a 
e    y    a
f    z    a
f    z    b
d    i    b
e    x    b
```

So far the closest I've gotten is this:

```
SELECT * FROM log AS a
WHERE a.3 in

(
   SELECT DISTINCT 3
   FROM log
   WHERE ((to_date(log_date)) >= (date_sub(current_date, 1)))
   AND 1 = 'f'
)
```

This gets me half way there, but it's not filtering on col2 and takes an extraordinarily long time to run, which can cause it to fail in my environment.

Is there a way to accomplish this using only Hive / Spark? I really don't want to have to download this file and run a python script on it, as it is several GB and my office wifi is slow :(

Answer (score 0):

Get all userids where `url = 'f'`.This will give you `(a,b)`
Use that to check userid for `actionid='x`'.This will give you `(a,b)`
Finally get all rows with userid from the above.

```
select * from log where userid in
(
    select distinct userid from log 
    where 
            actionid ='x' and 
            userid in (select distinct userid from log where URL='f')
)
```